# Proof of a property of a function defined on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with values in $\mathbb{R^+}$

Tags: measure-theory, pre-measure

> Let $X$  be a set and let $\alpha$ be defined for arbitrary subsets of $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$
> and satisfy
> $$0≤\alpha(E)≤α(E∪F)≤α(E)+α(F)$$
> when $E$ and $F$ are subsets of $X$. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the collection of all subsets $E$
> of $X$ such that
> $$α(A)=α(A∩E)+α(A∩E^c)$$
> for all $A⊂X$. If $\mathcal{S}$ is non empty, it is an algebra and $α$ is additive on $\mathcal{S}$.

This is problem 9P from Bartle. So far I have only been able to prove $\mathcal{S}$ is an algebra and one direction of $\alpha$-additiveness.

> $\mathcal{S}$ is an algebra.

Because $\exists S_o\in \mathcal{S}$, we have that $\alpha(\emptyset)=\alpha(\emptyset\cap S_o)+\alpha(\emptyset\cap S_o^C)\Rightarrow\alpha(\emptyset)=0$. Therefore, this allows us to conclude that $\alpha(A)=\alpha(\emptyset\cap A)+\alpha(X\cap A)$ and $\emptyset, X\in S$. By symmetry it is straightorward that $S$ is closed under complements.

By induction it remains to prove $A_1,A_2\in S\Rightarrow A_1\cup A_2\in S$. This indeed holds because for every $A$:

$$\alpha(A)=\alpha(A\cap A_1)+\alpha(A\cap A_1^C)=\alpha(A\cap A_1\cap A_2)+\alpha(A\cap A_1\cap A_2^C)+\alpha(A\cap A_1^C\cap A_2)+\alpha(A\cap A_1^C\cap A_2^C)$$

Because $(A_1\cap A_2)\cup (A_1\cap A_2^C)\cup (A_1^C\cap A_2)=A_1\cup A_2$ and $\alpha$ splits sums with an inequality, we have:

$$\alpha(A)\geq \alpha(A\cap (A_1\cup A_2))+\alpha(A_1^C\cap A_2^C)$$

The opposite inequality always holds. Therefore, $A_1\cup A_2\in \mathcal{S}$ as we wished to prove. $\square$

> $\alpha$ is additive on $S$.

Let $A_i\in \mathcal{S}$ be disjoint sets such that $\dot{\cup}_i A_i\in \mathcal{S}$. Using that $A_1\in \mathcal{S}$ yields that

$$\alpha(\dot{\cup}_i A_i)=\alpha(A_1)+\alpha(\dot{\cup}_{i>1} A_i)$$

Proceeding like this, we have:

$$\alpha(\dot{\cup}_i A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha(A_i)+\alpha(\dot{\cup}_{i>n} A_i)\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha(A_i)$$

Hence, $\alpha(\dot{\cup}_i A_i)\geq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha(A_i)$. Here, we have not yet used $\dot{\cup}_i A_i\in \mathcal{S}$ and I suspect this must be used to prove the reverse inequality.

Comment: are you sure “additive” doesn’t just mean finitely additive here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already established finite additivity with
$$\alpha(A_1\cup A_2)=\alpha((A_1\cup A_2)\cap A_1)+\alpha((A_1\cup A_2)\backslash A_1)= \alpha(A_1)+\alpha(A_2)$$
when $A_1,A_2\in \mathcal S$ are disjoint.

You cannot prove that $\alpha$ is countably additive on $\mathcal S$, as this is not in general true.  Let $X=\mathbb N$ and let $\alpha(A)=0$ if $A$ is finite, and $1$ if $A$ is infinite.

Then $E\in \mathcal S$ if and only if $E$ is either finite or co-finite.  Note that $\mathcal S$ is not closed under countable unions in the first place, but even when a countable union of sets in $\mathcal S$ happens to remain in $\mathcal S$, we do not have countable additivity, since, for example,
$$\alpha\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{n\}\right)=1\neq 0 =\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}\alpha(\{n\}).$$